# how to change uibutton title at runtime in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I know this question is asked many a times,and i am also implementing the same funda for chanding the title of the uibutton i guess.

Let me clarify my problem first. I have one uibutton named btnType, on clicking of what one picker pops up and after selecting one value,i am hitting done button to hide the picker and at the same time i am changing the the title of the uibutton with code

```
[btnType setTitle:btnTitle forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnType setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

But with my surpriaze,it is not changed and application crashes with signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I am not getting where i am making mistake.I have allocated memory to the btnType at viewdidLoad. Also I am using

```
-(IBAction)pressAddType
{
    toolBar.hidden = FALSE;
    dateTypePicker.hidden = FALSE;
}
```

event on pressing the button to open the picker. Also i would like to mention that i have made connection with IB with event TouchUpInside for pressAddType.

Any guesses? I will be grateful if you could help me.
Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
@interface AddSettingPage : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnType;
    NSString *btnTitle;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnType;
-(IBAction)pressAddType;//:(id)sender;
```

Also

```
@synthesize btnType,btnTitle;
```

Comment: can you show us your initialization code?

Comment: I updated my question with initialization code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try

```
[yourButton setTitle:@"your title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setTitle:@"your title" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[yourButton setTitle:@"your title" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

when the picker is dismissed, the button (which was the control that hold focus) will be in the selected state (or the highlighted .. check it out).

and stop using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` in the `forState:` parameter. it is not a state, it is an event. you are passing an event identifier instead of a state identifier

Answer (score 4):

The state you pass in setTitle should be something like UIControlStateNormal:

```
[b setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I used this code before,it is not making any change in the button title.

Comment: You may have other issues as well, but I accidentally used the wrong forState: last week and things didn't work until I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
- (IBAction) pressAddType;
```

declare

```
- (IBAction) pressAddType:(id)sender; //or  (UIButton *)sender
```

and define it like:

```
-(IBAction)pressAddType:(id)sender
{
    toolBar.hidden = FALSE;
    dateTypePicker.hidden = FALSE;

    [(UIButton *)sender setTitle:btnTitle forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [(UIButton *)sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to have your button as an ivar because it is passed as a parameter of the method when pressed.

Comment: I implemented this code but as soon as i press the button,the application creashes with nsexception : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AddSettingPage pressAddType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a31b60'. So i am not able to see the changes made.

Comment: You have to link the button you want to change to this method (In Interface Builder). Sorry, didn't say that. (Currently you are sending messages to AddSettingPage which doesn't have such a method, it has to be a UIButton.)

Comment: I already have linked the button in the same manner you mentioned.But i am not getting any solution!!

Answer (score 1):

This answer why not button title change only,EXC_BAD_ACCESS error only you getting when an object you trying to access those object is not in memory of stack or that object has null value. So my advice is please check your object (btnTitle) is in memory or not?

Comment: btnTitle is a string value where i am fetching my picker value,and by putting the nslog,i am able to get the idea that value is passed in that from the picker.